# django-autocomplete-light open popup on Create click

Tags: jquery, python, django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I'm developing a django form using **django-autocomplete-light**.

I would like to create a new choice in the autocomplete field: this is the tutorial I'm following: [link](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/master/tutorial.html#creation-of-new-choices-in-the-autocomplete-form).

The tutorial example is not exactly what I want: I would like to click on "Create new item" and show a popup displaying the model form.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For proper "add-another" popups like in django admin, try [django-addanother](https://github.com/jonashaag/django-addanother).